# Writing a generic ExceptionFitler in asp.net core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0

Below is my implementation. I have written a **CustomExceptionFilterAttribute** which inherits from **ExceptionFilterAttribute**. Each error is placed inside a if and else to generate proper result. What I would like to do is create a callback function so that I can remove if and else block and error can be handled in more generic way.

```
public class HostedServicesController : BaseController
{
   public IActioResult Index()
   {
      throw new NotFoundInDatabaseException("Error in Index Controller");
   }
}

public class NotFoundInDatabaseException : Exception
{
    public NotFoundInDatabaseException(string objectName, object objectId) :
            base(message: $"No {objectName} with id '{objectId}' was found")
        {

        }
}

public class CustomExceptionFilterAttribute :ExceptionFilterAttribute
    {
        private SystemManager SysMgr { get; }

        public CustomExceptionFilterAttribute(SystemManager systemManager)
        {
            SysMgr = systemManager;
        }
        public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
        {
            var le = SysMgr.Logger.NewEntry();
            try
            {
                le.Message = context.Exception.Message;
                le.AddException(context.Exception);

                var exception = context.Exception;
                if (exception is NotFoundInDatabaseException)
                {
                    le.Type = LogType.ClientFaultMinor;
                    context.Result = new NotFoundObjectResult(new Error(ExceptionCode.ResourceNotFound, exception.Message));
                }
                else if (exception is ConfigurationException)
                {
                    le.Type = LogType.ErrorMinor;
                    context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(new Error(ExceptionCode.NotAuthorised, exception.Message));
                }
                else
                {
                    le.Type = LogType.ErrorSevere;
                    context.Result = new InternalServerErrorObjectResult(new Error(ExceptionCode.Unknown, exception.Message));
                }
                le.AddProperty("context.Result", context.Result);
                //base.OnException(context);
            }
            finally
            {
                Task.Run(() => SysMgr.Logger.LogAsync(le)).Wait();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Dictionary` with a custom type for this. Think of something like this:

```
public class ErrorHandlerData
{
    public LogType LogType { get; set; }
    public string ExceptionCode { get; set; } // not sure if string
}

public class CustomExceptionFilterAttribute :ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    private static Dictionary<Type, ErrorHandlerData> MyDictionary = new Dictionary<Type, ErrorHandlerData>();

    static CustomExceptionFilterAttribute()
    {
        MyDictionary.Add(typeof(NotFoundInDatabaseException), new ErrorHandlerData 
            {
                LogType = LogType.ClientFaultMinor,
                ExceptionCode = ExceptionCode.ResourceNotFound
            };

            //general catch-all
        MyDictionary.Add(typeof(Exception), new ErrorHandlerData 
            {
                LogType = LogType.ErrorSevere,
                ExceptionCode = ExceptionCode.Unknown
            };
    }
```

So you can then use it like this:

```
public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
{
    var le = SysMgr.Logger.NewEntry();
    try
    {
        le.Message = context.Exception.Message;
        le.AddException(context.Exception);

        var exception = context.Exception;
        var exeptionType = exception.GetType();
        var errorHandlerData = MyDictionary.ContainsKey(exceptionType) ?
            MyDictionary[exceptionType] : MyDictionary[typeof(Exception)];

        le.Type = errorHandlerData.LogType;
        context.Result = new NotFoundObjectResult(new Error(errorHandlerData.ExceptionCode, exception.Message));

        le.AddProperty("context.Result", context.Result);
    }
    finally
    {
        Task.Run(() => SysMgr.Logger.LogAsync(le)).Wait();
    }
}
```